# Add congratulation message pong gosu

Tags: ruby, libgosu

I just started learning ruby and gosu. The code I am using right now is a reference from someone else code.

This is a 2 player Pong ruby game. The game is working and is able to play. I am trying to set it so that any player reach to the score of 10, the game will stopped and show the message "Player 1/2 wins" and prompt the players whether they want to continue playing.

My problem now is to show the message when one of the player score reach 10 followed by prompting the user if they want to continue.

(Disclaimer this is not my original code, i only use it to learn.)

```
if @player_1.score == 2
  @state = :stopped
  @message.draw_text('WIN',100,100,2)
end

if @player_2.score == 2
  @state = :stopped
end
```

This code is inside class Gosu::Window (I can't quite figure out how to put the whole code here since this is my first time)

[screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FgN3Z.png)

[screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b3naM.png)

Comment: it's much better to post your code as text in the question instead of as a screenshot. Also, can you be a little more clear on what exactlly is not working here? What error or erroneous behavior are you getting?

Comment: To elaborate @max's comment, there are two problems with links to pictures of code: 1) readers cannot cut-and-paste to run it, modified or not; and 2) links have a way of breaking in future, rendering questions incomplete for future readers, wasting their time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show your "WINNER SCREEN" you must manage status also in DRAW method.

This is an example of my code in an RPG Game...

```
  def draw
    case @state
    when ZOrdinals::GAME
      main_draw
    when ZOrdinals::MENU
      @main_menu.draw
    when ZOrdinals::BATTLE
      @battle.draw
    when ZOrdinals::DEAD
      @dead = Dead.new(self) if @dead.nil?
      @dead.draw
    end
  end
```

And this is the DEAD SCREEN code:

```
require_relative 'zordinals'

# Death screen

    class Dead
      def initialize(window)
        @window = window
        @image = Gosu::Image.new(File.dirname(__FILE__) + '../../images/die.png',
                                 tileable: false)
      end

      def update; end

      def draw
        @image.draw((ZOrdinals::SCREEN_WIDTH / 2) - (@image.width / 2),
                    (ZOrdinals::SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2) - (@image.height / 2),
                    ZOrdinals::BACKGROUND)
      end
    end
```

You can do something like this for your problem...